# Connecting to a particular machine in a server

Tags: server, ssh, virtualbox, transfer, scp

I am a beginner in this whole Ubuntu thing so I would appreciate to get some help, thanks !
I am trying to connect my Ubuntu machine (VirtualBox on Windows) to a distant server. After having done that connection, I wish to access a machine on that server.

Ex : I first enter "ssh mc@ssh.blablabla.com"
Then, I enter "ssh mc@machine1.blablabla.com" which connects me to the particular machine.

I was wondering how I could transfer files from my local repository to this particular machine. The problem is that the usual softwares (like WinSCP on Windows) only allow me to connect to the server but I cannot reach the particular machine on that server that interests me (the machines have many To of storage whereas simply connecting to the server only gives me 100 Mo).

It goes without saying that I cannot directly connect to the powerful machine without first connecting to the server.

Cheers !

Comment: Hi @Nmath, I'd like to know how I could transfer files from my virtual machine to a distant machine located in a distant server (I must enter two ssh queries to connect to this machine).

Comment: Option 1: Look up how to set up an *ssh tunnel* on the intermediate server. Option 2: Set up an SSH server on your local system, and launch scp from the powerful machine (client) to your local VM (server). Option 3: Script a relay on the intermediate server. Lots of creative solutions seem possible. I'm not seeing anything Ubuntu-specific in this question; it seems like a general networking question.

Comment: This is really a question about Winscp IMHO - see for example [Connect to FTP/SFTP server which can be accessed via another server only](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel)